# Custom sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I want to customize the Contact List in the SharePoint team site, to look like this :

```
http://192.185.166.160/~gigaworx/waleed/
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using jsLink. jsLink can be used to customize the look of the listview webpart .[This](http://zimmergren.net/technical/sp-2013-using-the-spfield-jslink-property-to-change-the-way-your-field-is-rendered-in-sharepoint-2013) will help you to get an idea of it.

Comment: how about action column ?more than one button in one column

Comment: You have to make few modifications and you can achieve this.